# Blazor WebAssembly Application Performs OIDC Silent Sign-in Multiple Times a Second

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I've encountered a very frustrating issue using .NET 5.0.2 Blazor WebAssembly and OIDC Authentication with IdentityServer4. Loading the page in a new tab works as expected, but when an error occurs on the page or the tab is reloaded, the application gets stuck in an infinite silent sign-in loop, making requests in sequence to `/connect/authorize`, `/.well-known/openid-configuration`, `/connect/token` multiple times a second through a hidden iframe. As the issue implies, it only occurs when a user is logged in.

**OIDC Authentication Configuraion**

```cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options => {
                options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
                options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "client-id";
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("profile");
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("roles");
                options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/";
                options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";

                options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
            });
```

**App.razor**

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <CascadingBlazoredModal>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <Authorizing>
                        <div class="screen-centred auth-spinner">
                            <Spinner />
                        </div>
                    </Authorizing>
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        } else {
                            <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingBlazoredModal>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**Identity Server Configuration**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContext")).UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            IIdentityServerBuilder? builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
                                                          options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                                                          options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                                                          options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                                                          options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                                                          // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                                                          options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                                                      })
                                                      .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                                                      .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                                                      .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                                                      .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddAuthentication();
        }
```

[Image of the Initiatior Chain from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY8Tx.png)

I've gone through all my code and the issue isn't caused by any of my uses of the AuthenticationStateProvider service, so I assume it is the result of a misconfiguration. I haven't found any other reports of this issue online, I'm not sure what I could've misconfigured that would cause this issue.

Comment: Hi Garett I am currently working on something very similar (ID4, WasmPWA Client stand alone, and separate gateway). I am not seeing this behaviour at all. I think we need to see a bit more of the code base.

Comment: @BrianParker Thanks for taking a look Brian, based on your comment I did some testing and discovered that this issue didn't occur when I ran the client on its own outside of the Asp.NET core hosted environment. I realized that I still have scaffolding auth code from the original project template on the server, which seems to have been causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through all the client code I could trying to identify the problem, I realized that the issue didn't occur when the WASM client was running standalone, instead of on an ASP.NET server. The server's Startup.cs class still contained code from the individual user accounts project template, which seems to have been the root cause.

I'm unable to reproduce the issue after removing the commented out lines from the Startup.cs class

```cs
namespace Server {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            // services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseSqlServer(
            //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            // services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            //
            // services.AddIdentityServer()
            //     .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
            //
            // services.AddAuthentication()
            //     .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            //services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            //services.AddBlazoredModal();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            // app.UseIdentityServer();
            // app.UseAuthentication();
            // app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```